# Word for 'stage elements'

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes everything you might find on a theatrical stage, including actors, props, and backdrops.

Comment: Stagecraft is close -- but not exactly what you are encompassing....

Comment: There is no such word. Actors cannot be classified with other elements in the theatre--they *are* theatre, everything else is secondary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Stage dressing** encompasses all the decorative items used to enhance the visual setting.  These items are rarely moved or even touched by the actors and are mostly used to help the designer establish place or time period as well as character detail. I am afraid that doesn't usually include actors as they are seldom static.
**Staging** is an instance or method of presenting a play or other dramatic performance and that can be said to include the actors, but it is less concerned with props generally.